# Meaning or definition of "substantional"

Tags: meaning, etymology

Recently I came across the word *substantional*.

What's its definition, and how can it be used in a sentence? Are there any common synonyms? Where did this word come from?

I suspect it's related to *substantial*, but it's not entirely clear.

[This was used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6336735/) in a context looking for reference back to an authority of some kind, but I'm unsure if this is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Most uses of *substantional* seems to be misspellings of *substantial*. The example that you linked to most definitely is.

The word does however have a meaning in itself. A *substantion* is the same as a noun, so *substantional* means *of noun*, just as *substantial* means *of substance*. It's used for example in the term *substantional linguistics*.

Answer (score 1):

The word is used infrequently and does appear to be a valid word, however the usage you cite is probably a misuse, intended to be "substantial" or "substantiating". The best contextual definition I can come up with is (*adj.*) - giving substance to, related to "substantiate" (*v.*) - to give substance to, and contrasting "substantial" (adj.) - having substance. It also can be used as "having to do with nouns", as "substantion" is defined as (*n.*) - a noun.

Answer (score 1):

According to many dictionaries, [there's](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/british/?q=substantional) [no](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substantional) [such](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/substantional) [word](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=substantional).

In fact it [can](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0882061054) be an adjective formed from to *substantion*, which is apparently a synonym for *substantive* (and also a place name), but this is very rare (and technical).

In the post you link to, this is almost certainly an error for *substantial*, as are many of the references to this word on [the internet](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1171&bih=802&source=hp&q=%22substantional%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=5014d35bb6efb157).

Comment: 'According to many dictionaries, there's no such word.' is misleading. Even OED claims to list less than 50% of 'English words', and has stated that a candidate word's not being listed is no proof that it is not a word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Not sure what you're getting at? Of course absence of a candidate word from dictionaries is no proof that it's not a "real word", hence why I say the word in question *is* a word in my second sentence!

Comment: 'According to many dictionaries, there's no such word.' I've only ever seen one example of a dictionary saying 'mirbane: apparently a meaningless word', and none saying anything like 'hsrraewv: there's no such word'. No dictionary has ever claimed 'if it's not in here, there's no such word'. But _you_ do.